# Array function that returns a multidimensional array with more than X elements?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to know if there is any native function or way to know those keys that have more than X elements and keep keys, I don't know if I'm making myself understood, so I'm going to do an example with those that are equal or greater than 2 elements

```
$array = Array ( 
                [A] => 1 
                [B] => 2 
                [C] => 3 
                [D] => Array 
                     ( 
                       [0] => 2 
                       [1] => 6 
                     ) 
                [F] => Array 
                     ( 
                       [0] => 9 
                       [1] => 3 
                     ) 
                [E] => 1)
               )
```

What i want

```
$array = Array ( [D] => Array 
                     ( 
                       [0] => 2 
                       [1] => 6 
                     ) 
                [F] => Array 
                     ( 
                       [0] => 9 
                       [1] => 3 
                     ) 
                )
```

Comment: `if(count($array[INDEX]) >= 2)` ???

Comment: @B001ᛦ this will not work in php >= 7.2 as an integer does not implement countable, you would need to check that first.

Comment: @MHewison absolutely correct, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code checks whether the current element is an array that contain >=2 elements:

```
$array = [
   "A" => 1,
   "B" => 2,
   "C" => 3,
   "D" => [2,6],
   "F" => [9,3],
   "E" => 1
];

 
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v) && count($v) >= 2) {
        $result[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Output of `$result`:

```
(
    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 6
        )

    [F] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: if the original array does not need to be preserved you would just unset the keys that don't meet the conditions ```if (!is_array($v) || !count($v) >= 2) { unset($array[$k]); }```

Comment: makes sense, but usually I don't overwrite variables/arrays and define new ones instead @MHewison

Answer (score 1):

For given format of array, you can use array_walk() and get desired output for the dyanamic $XElement

```
$final_arr = array();
$xElement = 1; // return all array which has more than 1 element
array_walk($array,function($value,$key, $xElement)  use(&$final_arr){
    if( is_array($value) && count($value) > $xElement ){
        $final_arr = array_merge($final_arr,array($key => $value));
    }
}, $xElement);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_arr);
```

check output here https://paiza.io/projects/0MaY5CSktb9Cmr8xJAskOQ?language=php